# Detecting client-aborted requests in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, request, detect, abort

I have a request in AppEngine that takes a little while to complete (many seconds). Is there a way to detect whether the user or some network problem has already aborted the request? This would allow me to save myself the server-load of continuing the result generation, which won't go anywhere anyways.

I tried the following in Dev-Mode, but neither worked (haven't checked yet whether it behaves differently in production mode):

- Checking whether resp.getOutputStream completes without throwing an IOException
- Checking whether there was an Interrupt sent to the servlet thread

Thanks, Markus

PS: I am really specifically interested in this question, not in ways to restructure my app to make the request faster or prevent aborts or other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to detect this from inside the app.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is possible at all on the App Engine, app engine doesn't allow in progress request. The response is sent to the client after that the handler/servlat has returned.

Answer (score 0):

Way late but this may be useful. In `Golang` you can detect interrupts using the `Context` package.

Here is a useful video of Francesc Campoy explaining it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSzR0VEraWw

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!